# Add tabs on node edit page

Tags: 7, nodes, ubercart, routes

How can i add a new tab in node tabs ( with edit, view tabs ) and show a page on this new tab ?
i am working on a shopping cart where i need to add a new configuration tabs with nodes and ubercart products.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a new URL by using [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

There, 'type' is set as [MENU_LOCAL_TASK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7) and URL is like 'node/%node/CUSTOM_CONFIG'.

Code snippet from the hook_menu in node.module:

```
 $items['node/%node/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'node_page_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'weight' => 0,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  );
```